# Being prompted for login credentials windows authentication asp.net mvc and knockoutjs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, windows-authentication

I am trying to access a site using windows authentication. The site is an asp.net mvc 4 application and uses knockout.js and jQuery for the client site. I am prompted for a login and if I cancel the login and reload the page it works ok, but for some pages it never works. But I have to keep doing that.

I have tried updating the security section of the web config. Configuration of a loopback address, removed the security section completely.

`      <system.webServer>

```
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="*" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>`


 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
   <pages>
   <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
     </pages>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="removed" validationKey="removed" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

The login prompt likely means that the browser is not automatically sending credentials. To test if that's all it is, try typing in your user credentials into that login prompt and see if it works.

For Chrome and Edge to automatically send your credentials, you have to add the website to the Trusted Sites in the Windows Internet Options.

If the site works when you hit Cancel on the login prompt, that sounds like you still have Anonymous Authentication enabled.

Comment: entering credentials does not work

Comment: i have anonymous authentication disabled, i have to reload the page after hitting cancel